# Error Message on Emailing - 998 octets

Tags: email, smtp

Why am I getting this following message and how can I sort it, please?

The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:

```
  'Gabe Clarke' on 06/10/2020 10:07
        550 maximum allowed line length is 998 octets, got 1012
```

Comment: It sounds like you have constructed an invalidly formatted email. Was the email constructed by your own software by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You attempted to send a message (to someone presumably running *exim*) that was not formatted according to standard line length limits.

Discussion of the upper limit can be found in [RFC 2822 Section 2.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.1.1), TL;DR: *[do] not to create such messages*.

Your solution is to find the software that created or transformed the message into exceeding this limit, and make it conform to the standard (correctly inserting line breaks). You will likely find the name of the orignal creator in a header like `User-Agent: Software Name vVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

When an email is replied to in Windows Outlook, an item is added to the "References" header. This header keeps growing in size on each reply until it is split up by Outlook at 1012 characters. The problem is that the RFC SMTP line length limit is 998 characters, resulting in many servers rejecting the message as having lines that are too long.

This issue has persisted for many years and Microsoft seems uninterested in fixing it. All it requires is for them to reduce the references header split length in Windows Outlook to 998 characters.

Comment: Related: [Automatically split References header at 998 characters in Exim](https://serverfault.com/questions/1109866/automatically-split-references-header-at-998-characters-in-exim)